# Show that $S$ is a real vector space using the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (what are "standard operations" on $\mathbb{R}^3$?)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My problem is:

Let $S = \{(x,y,0):x,y \in R\}$. Show that $S$ is a real vector space using the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What exactly are the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^3$? I'm not sure if it means closed under addition/scalar mult, or something else added to those, or anything else entirely.. I looked for a while trying to find out what standard operations for showing S is a real vector space is but nothing seems to tell me what standard is specifically..

edit: can someone tell me how to turn the E into the symbol meaning "is in"?

edit 2: taken from last comment in the answer, just to be sure, if I show all 8 axioms hold, I don't have to also show that the set is "closed under vector addition", "closed under scalar multiplication", and "has the 0 vector" separately, do I? Actually I believe those are the part of examples that say "together with these two operations, show ... is a real vector space". I believe "these two operations" refer to closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, and that the "standard operations on R3" are the 8 axioms. Am I right to assume this?

also, to verify my method of proving; while showing the 8 axioms hold, is it correct to let $u = (x,y,0)$, then show $u+v=v+u$ etc. by writing $u+v = (x,y,0)+(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ ..... then finishing off the proof, along with the other $7$?

Comment: Appendectomy, hemorrhoidectomy, tonsillectomy are the most common.

Comment: You could show that $S = \ker \phi$, where $\phi((x,y,z)) = z$.

Comment: @copper.hat This is the most elegant way. Very nice!

Comment: I havent learned kernals yet btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to show that all the axioms for a vector space hold, using normal vector addition and scalar multiplication as you normally would on elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: so do I have to apply each of the eight conditions such as 1: addition is communtative, 2: addition is associative.... etc. ?

Comment: @JL Exactly, you just have to check all of them.

Comment: Not usually. You already have a vector space, $\mathbb{R}^3$, you just need to show that $S$ is a subspace. In particular, if $x \in S$, check that $\lambda x \in S$ for any scalar $\lambda$, and if $x,y \in S$, check that $x+y \in S$.

Comment: so I'm having trouble figuring out if its acceptable to just: (show this set is closed under addition/scalar-multiplication by adding two vectors then multiplying a vector by k and showing its a non empty set by applying the 0 vector), or: (if I should write out each of the 8 rules applied to this set), after all, this section is titled "Basics of Real Vector Spaces" and the following section is titled "Subspaces". and I remember being told since we know something is a subspace of R thats why we can just apply the 3 steps.

Comment: @JL If you have learned about subspaces, then you can just do the subspace test. If you haven't, then you need to write out all the steps.

Comment: just to be sure, if I show all 8 axioms hold, I don't have to also show that the set is "closed under vector addition", "closed under scalar multiplication", and "has the 0 vector" separately, do I? Actually I believe those are the part of examples that say "together with these two operations, show ... is a real vector space". I believe "these two operations" refer to closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, and that the "standard operations on R3" are the 8 axioms. Am I right to assume this?

Comment: @JL Not quite. "closed under vector addition" and so on ARE some of the axioms. You need to show either that all eight axioms hold, using standard vector addition / scalar multiplication, or show that the space passes the subspace test. Nothing else.

Comment: i see now. took a long time to figure out "standard operations" meant addition and multiplication. one thing im unsure of though is how to apply each axiom to this type of a set, because I'm not sure how to read this set. Can you tell me how to read  S = {(x,y,0):x,y E R} and show an example of the first axiom being applied to it?

Comment: @JL I'm not sure which is your first axiom, but to for example show that $S$ is closed under addition, take two vectors $(a,b,0),(c,d,0) \in S$. Then $(a,b,0)+(c,d,0) = (a+c, b+d, o) \in S$, so $S$ is closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

edit 1: To get the symbol "is in" type "\in"

This is the best place to start to learn latex imo. http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/wiki/LaTex